# How to choose randomly between two particles to be trapped in a square lattice, given some conditions?

Tags: c, simulation, montecarlo

I'm simulating a square surface that is able to trap two kinds of particles, say particle #1 and particle #2.

I also need to calculate the averages of the coverages of the two trapped particles in such a surface. Those averages are taken after certain number of steps, for example, every 10 monte carlo steps I take the average for such coverages, then I print in a file each average and its respective "Y" value (while Y is less or equal than 1).

I'm trying to reproduce the results of a paper from scratch and there, Y is defined as the partial pressure of particle #1, and it's in the interval [0,1]. This parameter is used to decide which particle will be selected to be trapped on the surface. So, we draw a random number "r" (also in [0,1]). Then, if it is less than Y, we choose particle #1, otherwise, we select particle #2.

In the mentioned paper the authors simulate the interactions between both particles. The idea is to plot Y versus both coverages and obtain the same results they obtained before. But first I'm trying to "fill" that surface with atoms, before adding interactions between them.

The problem is that my code almost never selects the particle #1 and I don't know if this is related to the way I'm generating the random number "r" to select between particle #1 or #2. IN consequence the average of the coverage for the particle1 gives 0.000000.

A suggestion gave to me is that my program choose, with uniform probability, the float value r between 0 and 1 (both included) and compares such a number with Y value. Next, it assigns an empty cell to particle #1 only if r <= Y. However, since Y value is slowly increasing, starting from 0, there is a very little chance for particle #1 to occupy an empty cell.

But when I change the increment of Y by 0.1, I have the same problem while trying to choose between particles #1 and #2.

I can't think of any other way to incorporate "Y" in the simulation to be able to choose between these two atoms. I don't have a lot of programming experience but this simulation is not supposed to be difficult, and I don't know what to do with that. I will greatly appreciate any advice you could give to go further with my simulation.

Steps of the simulation:

1. Start with the random collision of a particle on a square lattice.
2. We chose particle #1 with a given probability Y and particle #2 with probability 1 — Y. ("Y is determined by the mole fraction of the particle #1 in the gas
   phase").
3. If the chosen particle is particle #1, we choose a site on the lattice at random. If that site is full the trial ends. Otherwise, particle #1 is trapped.
4. If the chosen particle is particle #2, we choose a site on the lattice at random. If that site is full the trial ends. Otherwise, particle #2 is trapped.

After this, I need to plot Y versus the coverages of both particles. I'm confused since they say "Y is a given probability" but, thee plot I need has the value of Y varying from 0 to 1.

Comment: You fill the grid with choices of particle 1 or 2. Early in the filling process, `Y` is low, and most choices are particle 2. As the grid is filled, more of the draws of grid position are filled, and, for each value of `Y`, you make only `MCSTEPS` attempts to fill a grid position—if the drawn position is filled, you do not put any particle in. So, by the time `Y` is larger and particle 1 is more likely to be drawn, you are filling fewer grid positions. Therefore, most of the grid positions are filled early with particle 2.

Comment: @mkrieger1: No, it does not.

Comment: It is not at all clear what probability distribution you want for these draws or what process you are modeling. You should clarify the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @EricPostpischil. Could adding the algorithm I'm following further clarify the kind of process I'm modeling? The simulation is based on the Kinetic Montecarlo Method for the adsorption of atoms/molecules on a surface. Specifically, on the ZGB model. They only specify that `Y` is in the interval `[0,1]` and to choose between the type of particle/atom/molecule to be trapped they must draw a random number  `r` between `0` and `1`. If such a number is less than `Y` we choose the particle #1, otherwise we choose  #2.

Comment: I'm stuck in the part where the program needs to select between those particles, which is essentially the first part of the whole simulation. That's because I'm not sure how to include `Y` properly on it. Once I fix this, I'll be able to add interactions between them. The following parts are easy since they basically regard filling cells depending if they are already occupied or not. But the part with `Y` and `r` really confuses me.

Comment: @Auyk Note that `rand() % max` will never return `max` so the "we draw a random number "r" (also in [0,1])" is more like "we draw a random number "r" (also in [0,1))"  (1 is not included in the range - or perhaps `..._MAX` needs a different name.

Comment: Describe the simulation thoroughly and clearly. E.g., one might model an environment where there is a proportion of Y type-1 particles and 1−Y type-2 particles, and random particles (with that distribution) fall in random places on the grid. And you model that for some number of falls, do some calculations with it, then reset the grid and model the same situation with a different Y.

Comment: Or another model might be similar but Y is changing over time, and, for some reason, particles never fall where other particles fell. That seems to be what you are currently modeling. But what that achieves is unclear. (Also, in both this and the first model, why do particles never fall in the same place?) If neither of these is the desired model, describe the model.

Comment: @Auyk Aside: Why `float` anything here?  Rather than mix `double` math` with `float` math and incur subtle FP effects of that mix, consider using `double` throughout.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @chux-ReinstateMonica. I'll do that. Also `1` is included in the range of `r`, it was a typo, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, @EricPostpischil. I just edited my post and added the steps of the simulation I'm trying to perform

Comment: The newly added steps of the simulation are completely inadequate. Your code changes `Y`, and the steps give no reason why.

Comment: This is why I'm confused. Then how is made a plot of `Y` vs the coverages? They plot the coverages as functions of `Y`

Comment: One possibilities is that multiple simulations are done. An empty grid is initialized, some number of particle drops are done with a given Y, and the resulting coverage is memorized. Then Y is changed, and the grid is completely reset to empty, and a new simulation of some number of particle drops are done. This is done repeatedly, with a new Y and an empty starting grid each time. Whatever it is, you need to understand the simulation and be able to describe it thoroughly before you write code for it.

Comment: Hmm. That could be possible. Could it be also possible to fix the value of Y at first, outside any loop, then perform what is inside the loops, and finally update the value of Y in the same code? Maybe this question is stupid